# Hide the environment.js in production environment in angular project

Tags: angular, project, production-environment

I have recently get requirement that hide or protect **environment.js** file to download in production environment. These fill are javascript file so if we remove or access other place not proper solution. if anyone know that how restrict/protect environment.js file in angular output folder. It will help to me.

Comment: What do you mean? If it's not accessible, how does the app get access to its configuration?

Comment: You can block direct access via an `.htaccess`, `nginx.conf` or some other hosting settings

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you encrypt it?

Lot's of company who have their stuff in cloud are adding that requirement for production environment.

https://medium.com/nontechcompany/secure-angular-configuration-credentials-in-containerized-environment-as-of-2021-a7f36ed676ed